Could Harry have deduced that Snape was on his side because Snape summoned help in Order of the Phoenix?
Harry spends much of Half Blood Prince and Deathly Hallows thinking Snape is a traitor. However, given that Snape summoned the Order to the Department of Mysteries at the end of Order of the Phoenix, could Harry have deduced that Snape was on his side (or, even further, that Snape was a double agent)? It seems plausible - Harry knows that Snape is the one who summoned the Order, and that it's hard to imagine summoning the Order could benefit Voldemort. As I recall, this was not addressed either when Snape was explaining his actions to other Death Eaters (he e.g. mentioned that he did his best to stop Quirrell during the events of Philosopher's Stone because he was unaware that Quirrell = Voldemort), but the other Death Eaters presumably did not know that Snape is the one who summoned the Order.
I'm most interested in the books.
Related: Did the Order of the Phoenix know that Snape was a double-agent? If the answer to this question turns out to be "yes", then it's possible the entire Order could've deduced it.

The issue with the double agents is that their allegiance is inherently difficult to prove. This is a part of the position Snape was in. He can't take actions (or allow inaction) which lead to jeopardising his status on both sides, so he had to make moves which are uncomfortable for either side from time to time to not blow his cover.
Snape definitely had some sort of explanation for his actions to Death Eaters as to why he did such and such even if it isn't always provided in the books, otherwise he wouldn't have been a double agent anymore. That same explanation was evidently enough for Death Eaters as to why he is on their side, and so Harry could have known or imagined it too.
I can only speculate on the reason, of course, but it seems obvious to me. Harry knew that he alerted Snape. Even if everyone else keeps silent, Harry would surely tell the Order that he had notified Snape about the situation. If it turns out that Snape knew about this and did nothing, it would cast a serious doubt on whether he is on the side of the Order. So he had to relay the information to the Order. Maybe the help arrived to the Ministry later than it could have to provide the illusion that Snape didn't do this as soon as possible to buy Death Eaters some time.
So individual actions favouring each of the sides can't show the true side Snape was on unless it's some complete betrayal like aiding in the destruction of horcruxes. The only way to truly know that was to know the story with Lily and see Snape's patronus. Only Dumbledore knew about it, so everyone else had to trust Dumbledore's judgement. Harry wasn't blindly trusting Dumbledore, so he didn't completely trust Snape either.

Note that Snape also told the order late enough that Harry & Co. had time to fly from Scotland to London on Threstrals, get into the dept. of mysteries, look through all the doors until they found the hall, go fetch the prophecy, and get into a fight with Voldemort's people, all before the order (who had access to instant travel) showed up.

It's part of an ongoing sub-plot that lasts all through the seven-book saga. There is a mutual animosity between Harry and Snape. Harry has fixed ideas about Snape that he won't change, even when he is shown to be wrong. Harry thought Snape was trying to kill him. No, Quirrell was trying, and Snape saved Harry. Even so, Harry hangs on to his suspicions about Snape and won't let go. This is a character flaw on his part. It is a major part of their relationship.  Only with Snape's death does Harry finally come to admit that he had misjudged Snape.

Harry did not misjudge Snape after the end of first year. Harry correctly assumed that Snape: 1. Hated him, and 2. Did not want to kill him, and might protect his life. When Snape died, Harry understood Snape's rationalizations behind those two seemingly contradictory things.
